# I paid someone to sand and restain an oak table, when I wipe it with a paper towel stain comes off, how do I fix it

Tags: wood, furniture, wooden-furniture, staining

I paid someone to sand and refinish my kitchen table. The table is rubbing off stain when wipped with a dry paper towel. I don't trust their ability to fix it so I am trying to fix it myself.

They claimed they used min wax colonial maple stain, and then general finishes poly both oil based.

I am not sure how to fix this especially with stain wipping off. They have had it completed, drying, for a week. I am hoping to not have to strip and start all over as the color is fine I just want to seal it and make it a functional table again.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm not sure we'll be able to figure this out remotely, although a picture would help

Comment: If stain is wiping off, they didn't poly it. I've not known stain to rub off after a poly is applied

Comment: I agree that there is no sealer or if there was it was not properly applied, possibly a bad batch.

Comment: Can I apply poly over the stain even if it's still coming off?

Comment: i like acrylic-based because it does not yellow like poly. if it's completely dry, you can go ahead and seal the sucker up with clear acrylic.

Comment: I ended up using a stripper, then sanding and finally applying my own clear poly on top. Took quite a while and a lot of effort but it looks beautiful now.